# How many hours of sleep “is” or “are” needed?

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement

Time, distance, weight are treated as singular, like "3 hours is too long." Then, in this instance,

> How many hours of sleep is /are needed to keep fit?"

Is "is" correct?

Comment: Part-1 of the post, the presumption, is invalid. Part-2, for the example sentence, for the question "Is *is* correct", the answer would be 'Yes', but not deriving from the presumption.

Comment: "3 hours is a long time" = "the period is a long time".  "How many hours of sleep are needed" = "how many periods of sleep are needed".

Answer (score 4):

When time, distance, money, and weight are considered as collective units of measure, they are considered singular because they're [collective](https://www.e-education.psu.edu/styleforstudents/c1_p6.html):

> Three hours **is** a long time.
>   Fifty kilometers **is** too far to walk.
>   Five thousand dollars **is** too much for that ratty old fur coat.
>   Four hundred kilograms **is** more than my extended family of five weighs. (The final verb might be "weigh" in British English. I can't say for sure.)

However, when the units are considered as separate entities, they're considered plural:

> "Many hours **are** lost in arguing over even obvious errors." (Kris's example)
>   **Those** last five kilometers **were** killers, each for a different reason: crocodiles, mosquitoes, rattlesnakes, robbers, and army ants.
>   There **are** fifty silver dollars in the piggy bank. (There are 50 **coins**....)
>   The last three kilograms **were** lost at a rate of one per week instead of one per day. (Separate units of weight)

Comment: I could guess collective means whole and separate means some part of the whole..? Thanks for big help!

Answer (score 0):

> Three hours is a long time.

is similar to

> A three-hour duration is a long time.