# Using "that" with plural

Tags: grammatical-number, questions, that

I used the following grammar construction recently, and got corrected by someone:

> How many cards are that?

Is using "that" when referring to multiple cards (a stack of cards) valid grammar? I feel like I've seen it being used multiple times on the internet.

Another example:

> He offered me 1,000,000 dollars in cash.

> Damn, how many stacks of one-dollar bills are that?

Comment: Does this help answer your question? https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/104034/how-many-hours-of-sleep-is-or-are-needed

Comment: You're talking about the total: How many *is that*? What total *does that* make? But not *are that* or *do that*. Oh, and seeing sh*t multiple times on the internet is not a model to follow.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How many hours of sleep “is” or “are” needed?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/104034/how-many-hours-of-sleep-is-or-are-needed)

Comment: As there are duplicates, I'll convert my answer to a comment. I agree that your first version should be corrected. One way could be to use the singular "How many cards is that?" when, for example, someone passes you a hand of cards. Or, in the plural, I would phrase it as "How many cards are there?"

Comment: Just to clarify, using "that" is not a problem in itself. In fact, it is the "that" that makes it singular: "How many cards is that [amount]?" As @WeatherVane shows, it changes to plural when you take the focus of "that" collective amount and onto the cards themselves.

Comment: 'That are ...' is ungrammatical and sounds terrible.  And the construction 'How many Ns are that?' is likewise best treated with the longest bargepole one can find. The ' ... are needed?' example above is not identical; while 'How many  hours of sleep is needed?' includes a time measure treated as singular (cf '£30 is needed'), 'six balls are needed' is of course fine. 'How many Ns is that / does that make?', with a singular verb form, are idiomatic.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, but I wasn’t expecting the sudden feistiness. I'm not a native speaker, have you ever heard of language immersion? Picking up wrong speech patterns is normal.

Comment: I'd say that singular "is" is correct. "How many cards is that?" is a _possible_ interrogative counterpart of "That is x cards", where "are" is clearly not possible.